# How to use `image` to display a matrix in its conventional layout?

Tags: r, image, matrix, plot, transpose

I have a matrix defined as follows

```
dataMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(400), nrow=40)
```

then `dataMatix` is plotted to the screen using the following

```
image(1:10, 1:40, t(dataMatrix)[, nrow(dataMatrix):1])
```

can someone explain how the third argument of the image function works ? I'm particularly confused by what happens inside `[]`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing better than an illustrative example. Consider a `4 * 2` integer matrix of 8 elements:

```
d <- matrix(1:8, 4)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    5
#[2,]    2    6
#[3,]    3    7
#[4,]    4    8
```

If we `image` this matrix with `col = 1:8`, we will have a one-to-one map between colour and pixel: colour `i` is used to shade pixel with value `i`. In R, colours can be specified with 9 integers from 0 to 8 (where 0 is "white"). You can view non-white values by

```
barplot(rep.int(1,8), col = 1:8, yaxt = "n")
```

[image]

**If `d` is plotted in conventional display, we should see the following colour blocks:**

```
black  |  cyan
red    |  purple
green  |  yellow
blue   |  gray
```

---

Now, let's see what `image` would display:

```
image(d, main = "default", col = 1:8)
```

[image]

We expect a (4 row, 2 column) block display, but we get a (2 row, 4 column) display. So we want to transpose `d` then try again:

```
td <- t(d)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4
#[2,]    5    6    7    8

image(td, main = "transpose", col = 1:8)
```

[image]

Em, better, but it seems that the row ordering is reversed, so we want to flip it. In fact, such flipping should be performed between columns of `td` because there are 4 columns for `td`:

```
## reverse the order of columns
image(td[, ncol(td):1], main = "transpose + flip", col = 1:8)
```

[image]

Yep, this is what we want! We now have a conventional display for matrix.

Note that `ncol(td)` is just `nrow(d)`, and `td` is just `t(d)`, so we may also write:

```
image(t(d)[, nrow(d):1])
```

which is what you have right now.

Comment: Aha ! so 
[, ncol(td):1]  # are columns
and
[ nrow(td):1,] # are rows

Comment: @ Li, yes thank you very much, very clear. I would be happy with a reference to the documentation ;-)

Comment: @ Li . Done ! Found it !